# Get react context data in ResizeObserver callback

Tags: reactjs, callback, components, resize-observer

I have the following React `getView` component

```
function getView() {
  const mainContext = useContext(MainContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    // data has values here
    const activeDiv = document.getElementById('active-div');
    new ResizeObserver(dataMethod).observe(activeDiv);

  }, [mainContext?.data])

  function dataMethod() {
    let data = mainContext?.data;  // data is always empty here
  }

  ...
}
```

For some reason `mainContext?.data` is always empty.  How can I access the `mainContext?.data` in the `dataMethod()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the behaviod "data is always empty here" but the possible error you are getting is due to you are not calling unobserve/disconnect of the ResizeObserver instance in the cleanup function of your useEffect. So you end up with (more than 1) Observer and your function is called from each of them on resize, utilizing closure-captured values that were captured at the moment when `observe` was called.

What can you try - add a useRef variable to eliminate possible closure issues and to prevent the need to create/remove ResizeObserver on `mainContext.data` changes.

```js
const mainContext = useContext(MainContext);
const dataRef = useRef(mainContext?.data);

useEffect(() => {
  dataRef.current = mainContext?.data;
}, [mainContext?.data]);

useEffect(() => {
  const dataMethod = () => {
    let data = dataRef.current;
    console.log("dataMethod data: ", data);
  };

  const activeDiv = document.getElementById("active-div");
  const obs = new ResizeObserver(dataMethod);
  obs.observe(activeDiv);

  return () => {
    obs.disconnect();
  };
}, []);
```

[image: Edit determined-water-9tribt]